# Reducing give in bi-polar stepper motor axel

Tags: motor, stepper-motor

I have the NEMA-11 bi-polar stepper motor (http://www.active-robots.com/3322-0-28sth32-nema-11-bipolar-stepper-with-100-1).

The issue is that I am able to turn the axel about 5-8 degrees without applying much force. This is an issue as what I am connecting it to can sometimes lightly pull causing the position to be inaccurate.

I am new to stepper motors. What can I do to reduce this?

Comment: Put a position encoder on the shaft so that you can measure its rotation - which sort-of violates the point in using a stepper... A stepper may not be the best choice for your application - maybe consider a servo or a simple geared DC motor with encoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is called 'backlash'.

The data sheet for the motor shows that it is a gearbox output, with a fractional degree step angle. As such, it is unlikely you are moving the motor itself, all of the movement will be due to the tolerances of the gear teeth.

Preloading the output shaft with a spring (for non-continuous rotation) or a torque motor should remove most of the effect of backlash.

An alternative is to move away from stepper motors, use a servo with an absolute encoder on the output shaft, which will drive the motor such that the output shaft is always maintained in the wanted position.

Comment: I do not have enough time to make amendments for now but it is good to know the correct terminology, thank you. Each time the motor stops, I may push the device to the limit of either clockwise or anticlockwise for now, hopefully this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that, in the picture in the link, you are talking about the right-hand shaft. This is the motor shaft, and you should not connect to that. I believe you'll find that the left-hand shaft is much "stiffer" and you should connect to that one instead.

When not energized, stepper motors display what is called "detent torque", which can be quite low, and I suspect that is what  you are dealing with. The motor (on the left) drives a 100:1 gearbox on the right, and this produces an output with 1/100 the motion but 100 times the force (torque). Backdriving the gearbox output should be pretty near impossible with finger pressure.

If I am wrong, and you are turning the right-hand shaft easily, you have a badly defective gearbox.

As for the motor shaft, try driving it with an appropriate driver at zero step rate, and you should get much more resistance to motion.

Comment: The device I am connecting to is reasonably heavy so I chose to use the larger shaft. I am able to rotate the shaft on the right as well without too much effort unfortunately.

Comment: @Thomas1982 - My apologies. I did not look closely enough at the picture, and flubbed the identification of motor/gearbox. You were correct, and the larger diameter shaft is the one you want. I'll edit my answer. With that said, your shaft play seems excessive. But try running current through the motor, and see if that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Backlash is a common problem in motion systems using gears or belts or pulleys. A typical problem might be in a CNC milling machine where the user notices that when the direction is reversed that the cutter doesn't move until all the backlash has been taken up. This causes cutting errors. Many systems have built-in **backlash compensation** and this approach may be good enough for your application.

To use backlash compensation your program needs to detect changes in direction of the motor and make a step move the correct amount to take up all the slack. The exact number of steps would be determined by trial and error or measurement. If you set the motor oscillating back and forward by the backlash amount the gearbox shaft should be just on the edge of moving.